Can we Deploy Web Application in Azure OpenAI of Production Level
I have created azure ai search service and used Text split skillset and made index. I also deployed a web Application but have a question that If I want to create to production level, which means that Can we create/deploy a web application in such a way that in web application, I can upload document and ask questions and get answers there and then.
The web application is created using Azure AI Search and it has documents that are stored in Azure Blob Storage. If I want to create Production level Web Application where we can upload Document and ask questions and get answers, Is it possible or not?
Please Guide.
Thanks in Advance!!!

Short answer is Yes, its possible.
On the backend, you can create/link with your index via Azure SDK. Your pipeline/workflow would look something like this on high level:

Upload document
Process document
Upload to an existing index via Azure SDK (create index first if necessary)
Link with the new index and do Q/A
Remove document from index via Azure SDK (delete index if necessary)

Note: You probably need to create index for each user or each session depending on how you want to design your application.

Can you please tell step by step procedure in detail that I need to follow.
